How to create a Tuple2, Tuple3 etc in Java Reactor?
Created this question and answer to help others with quick lookup of how to create a Reactor Tuple, such as reactor.util.function.Tuple2<T1,T2>
I couldn't find any example constructor on the Javadoc for Tuple2 so had to do some more digging.

A general tuple class is a terrible idea and a terrible design.  Which will be easier for other programmers to understand:  Tuple<String, LocalDate> or public record Person(String name, LocalDate dateOfBirth) { }?

@VGR It is bad if used in public interface, but  if it doesn't leave class or even method it is fine.

None of that is relevant to the question.  The class is already part of the existing library, and the OP is asking how to construct an instance.

Use reactor.util.function.Tuples.of(T1 t1, T2 t2)
Note that it uses the Tuples class.
Method signature:
static <T1,T2> Tuple2<T1,T2> of(T1 t1, T2 t2)

More methods and constructors available in the Javadoc

There are plenty of tuple libraries.
One of them is Java SDK, which have Map.Entry. You can create it with Map.entry().
There are also org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair from
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>

It use Pair.of() method.
There are plenty of others. Most of them use similar approach.
To answer your specific question: There is reactor.util.function.Tuples.of() method.
